# How to model a property with two different formats and ranges

Tags: data-structures, json, schema

I am designing a JSON based data schema to describe the visual appearance of blocks similar to HTML elements.
It should feel familiar for somebody knowledgable in HTML/CSS but is more restrictive due to constraints of the enviroment that it will be used in.

Now I am unsure how to model "width".
Acceptable are either pixel values between 0 and positive infinity or percent values between 0 and 100, but no points, ems, rems or whatever else.

I have three alternatives in mind:

1st: One property with varying formats

```
{
    "width": 300,
    "width": "300",
    "width": "300px",
    "width": "50%"
}
```

2nd: Two separate mutual exclusive properties

```
{
    "width": 300,
    "width-relative": 50
}
```

3rd: One property and a boolean flag

```
{
    "width": 50,
    "relative-width": true
}
```

They all have their pros and cons in terms of similarity to HTML/CSS, ease of validation, conciseness, consistency, ...
I have a favorite, my colleague has a different one.

**Wich one would you choose and why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just say in a year from now you decide that you need support `em` or whatever other type for width. 
For compatibility I would go for the first alternative as I think this change might be difficult with one of the other two.

Another solution might be to define types:

```
{
    "width": 50, //Always a number
    "type": "absolute" //Possible values: "px", "%", "relative", ...
}
```

So you are still able to be backwards compatible and the evaluation should be pretty easy.

The `type` field could also be optional.

Answer (score -1):

the 1st so it matches actual css, and is the simplest.

Comment: I see your point, but for validation (using JSON Schema) this is most complicated...

Comment: @hielsnoppe does anyone use json schema ?

Comment: Well, I do. :-) But also for validation in code or anywhere else this seems more complicated to me. But of course it is the easiest for the user.